# Drupal 7 change default user login functionality

Tags: forms

I want to change the default login functionality to look at a web service and if true log in else do not log in.

I have tried to use in `hook_form_alter`

```
 $form['#submit'] = 'user_change_login_submit'; 
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]= 'user_change_login_submit';
```

But it doesn't call this function.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/cas that would be a better way for alternative authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar functionality in a project a while ago and I solved it by adding a validation handler and doing the check in that.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Replace the drupal authenticate function is it's used as validation.
  if (isset($form['#validate']) && is_array($form['#validate']) && ($key = array_search('user_login_authenticate_validate', $form['#validate']))) {
    $form['#validate'][$key] = 'mymodule_login_authenticate_validate';
  }
}

function mymodule_login_authenticate_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // Set 
  $account = mymodule_authenticate($form_state);
  if ($account) {
    $form_state['uid'] = $account->uid;
  }
}


function mymodule_authenticate($form_state) {
  // Your magic code here
  // In my project I either created a new user or updated an existing user and set $account as that.

  // And if everything went well in your code, finalize login and return account
  user_login_finalize($form_state['values']);
  return $account;
}
```